# What kind of solenoid is this?

Tags: solenoid, solenoid-valve

My electrical water timer broke, and interested to see its inside I opened up and found this (image) solenoid. I'm not sure what type it is.

The whole thing runs on 2xAA (2x1.5V) batteries, but it must be boosted as I've tried 2xAA and it did nothing.

One lead is white, one lead is yellow. On the left side there is a tap that is actuated by the solenoid, but I can press it a bit and then it "clicks" and its locked in place.

[image]

1. does somebody now specifically know what type this is?
2. does it have polarity, or could I try to attach 2xAA in any configuration?

Comment: those leads look un-insulated ... danger of short-circuit

Comment: Try energizing both polarities.

Comment: If the timer was broken is it possible the solenoid was the defective part?  Try using a DVM to measure the DC resistance across the leads, an open circuit may indicate that the solenoid coil is defective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copper wires have a clear coating of polyurethane which is an insulator. So you can't easily connect a battery there.

Strip some of the Plastic insulation from the yellow and white ends and connect those to your batteries.

If you make a good electrical connection you should see a small spark when you disconnect it. if you see no spark the solenoid coil is probably damaged.

As it is battery operated, the solenoid may be a latching type and require opposite polarity to move in each direction.

I can see no reason why they would use a solenoid that requires boosted voltage.

Comment: Thank you for your great insight!